# How to open Powershell with cmd and use a .ps1 file

Tags: powershell

I try to open a ps1  powershell file thats updates a gitrepo

i have  tryed

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%USERPROFILE%\folder1\update.ps1'
```

this is working but when it comes to a  requirements.txt promt writes error of not found that  file i think powershell is not inside this folder directly so it  cant find that file what is needed

if i make this

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\ & REM First change to the batch file folder


echo Points as at = %time% %date%> updatebing_log.txt & REM create a simple logfile with time and end result of the batch run
echo ============================folder1=========================== >> updatebing_log.txt

cd folder1\
start powershell
cd %USERPROFILE%\folder1
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%USERPROFILE%\folder1\update.ps1'


echo Waiting seconds
timeout /t 10 /nobreak > NUL
```

it is working
but it opens  a cmd (bash file) promt  and a  powershell then it cd to folder
powershell do  nothing then
inside cmd i see  that the ps1  file  is executed and alsow works with the requirements.txt

Comment: ``cd %USERPROFILE%\`` only changes to the batch-file folder if the batch file happens to be located in `%USERPROFILE%`. Use `cd /d "%~dp0"` instead. What is the purpose of `start powershell`? It starts an interactive session in a new window.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do. Why are you mixing .bat/.cmd code with PowerShell, when you can do this with PowerShell directly?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment. Here's what your code is doing. Thus the response you're seeing.

```
# Run this in cmd.exe
cd %USERPROFILE%\ & REM First change to the batch file folder


echo Points as at = %time% %date%> updatebing_log.txt & REM create a simple logfile with time and end result of the batch run
echo ============================folder1=========================== >> updatebing_log.txt

cd folder1\
# Start a PowerShell interactive session
start powershell
cd %USERPROFILE%\folder1

# Start a new PowerShell session from cmd.exe and run this code
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& "$env:USERPROFILE\folder1\update.ps1" # note the profile change I made for you.

# Run this in cmd.exe on Powerhell exit
echo Waiting seconds
timeout /t 10 /nobreak > NUL
```

If that is not the flow you were after, then you need to rethink this.

Comment: becorse  i cant make a code inside commend   i have made an  answer hope its better . sorry for bad english

Answer (score -1):

i made this at work it looks likke it works but dont know i try to show the working directory but it want show it only shows were the ps1 call file is

i made a test.bat

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%USERPROFILE%\Brewd\updatebrewdall.ps1'"
```

and updatecall.ps1

```
cd "folder1\"


powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '.\update.ps1'"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
# now back to previous directory
cd ..\
cd "folder2\"
"$([Environment]::CurrentDirectory)\$ComputerName"
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '.\update.ps1'"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
# now back to previous directory
cd ..\
cd "folder3\"
"$([Environment]::CurrentDirectory)\$ComputerName"
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '.\update.ps1'"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```